# Select no Laravel esta retornando o nome da coluna(Eloquent)

Tags: sql, laravel

Estou com problema para retornar somente o valor do select no caso é o nome ,mas esta retornando como se fosse string e esta com nome da coluna.

> Controller

```
public function resultadoconsulta(Request $request){                    
        $nome = $request-> nomeCompleto;
        $data = $request-> dataNascimento;

 $paciente = Pacientes::select('nome_completo')                             
             ->where('nome_completo',$nome)                                 
             ->where('data_nascimento',$data)                               
             ->get();

 return view('/resultadoconsultapaciente')->withPaciente(json_encode($paciente));}
```

> View

```
{{$paciente}}
```

> Resultado

```
[{"nome_completo":"Leonardo Amancio de Araujo"}]
```

Comment: Porque tá usando json_encode?

Comment: Pesquisa também poderia ser melhor

Answer (score 1):

> Controller

```
public function resultadoconsulta(Request $request){                    
        $nome = $request-> nomeCompleto;
        $data = $request-> dataNascimento;

 $paciente = Pacientes::select('nome_completo')                             
             ->where('nome_completo',$nome)                                 
             ->where('data_nascimento',$data)                               
             ->get()->first(); 
//use o first() para obter o primeiro registo da lista, caso contrário devolve uma collection


//outra forma de passar a variável à View
 return view('/resultadoconsultapaciente', compact('paciente'))
}
```

> View

```
{{$paciente->nome_completo}}
```

Comment: O resultado foi quase o mesmo :
{"nome_completo":"Leonardo Amancio de Araujo"}

Comment: Usou o ->first();  no query?

Comment: usei sim ,consegui resolver assim: coloquei na view 
@foreach($paciente as $pac) e depois {{$pac->nome_completo}}